# Detect individual beacon using proximity SDK

Tags: android, kotlin, proximity, estimote, android-ibeacon

I have used [this example](https://github.com/Estimote/Android-Proximity-SDK/tree/master/example/AndroidThingsApp) to detect beacons. In this example, Is it possible to detect which beacon is triggering the action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with the [`ProximityZoneContext`](https://estimote.github.io/Android-Proximity-SDK/com.estimote.proximity_sdk.api/-proximity-zone-context/index.html) object that's being passed to the `onEnter`/`onExit` actions:

```
val proximityZone = ProximityZoneBuilder()
            .forTag("my-beacons")
            .inNearRange()
            .onEnter {
                Log.i(TAG, "onEnter: ${it.deviceId}")
            }
            .build()
```